# Element implicitly has 'any' type because type has no index signature

Tags: typescript, types, functional-programming, typescript2.0

I'm trying to implement something like `Maybe.withDefault` in TypeScript:

```
const locale = 'en-US'; //navigator.language
const systemLanguage:Language = withDefault(locale, 'en');


const languages = {en: <'en'>'en', mk: <'mk'>'mk', es: <'es'>'es'};
type Language = keyof typeof languages;


const withDefault = (candidate: string, def: Language): Language =>
  languages[langCandidate] ? languages[langCandidate] : def;
```

While I understand how the `string` is conflicting with `Language`, I wonder how do I remedy this without changing the languages structure which gives me tight types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by introducing an intermediate type that can be indexed either by `Language` or string, and introducing an intermediate function that implicitly converts `languages` to that type (conversion succeeds without type cast because these types are one-way compatible):

```
const languages = {en: <'en'>'en', mk: <'mk'>'mk', es: <'es'>'es'};
type Language = keyof typeof languages;


type LanguageLookup = {[n in Language | string]: Language};

function languageLookup(language: string, lookup: LanguageLookup): Language | undefined {
    return lookup[language];
}

const withDefault = (candidate: string, def: Language): Language =>
    languageLookup(candidate, languages) || def;
```

Comment: Thanx mate / Фала братче / Muchas gracias